# Getting Sentry errors from RQ workers in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sentry, python-rq

I have a Flask server that is registered to sentry using `raven.contrib.flask`'s `Sentry(app, dns=...)` object.  I also have some python-rq workers for working on async background processes.  I found [this documentation](http://python-rq.org/patterns/sentry/) that seems to state that I can just register sentry in my start_worker script like so:

```
with Connection(redis_client):
    worker = Worker(map(Queue, ['default']))
    client = Client('<MY_SENTRY_DSN>', transport=HTTPTransport)
    register_sentry(client, worker)
    worker.work()
```

Where redis_client is my connection to redis using `StrictRedis(host=...)`.  These workers work fine, but when I force the job they're working on to raise an Exception, I'm not seeing any errors on Sentry, but I am seeing the raised Exception in the worker's error logs.

My Sentry project is setup to allow all domains currently.  Is there anything special I have to do to get these errors to show up correctly in Sentry?

Comment: Should be working, unclear why it's not. I set up a demo project showing how to use Sentry with RQ, hopefully that sheds some light? https://github.com/getsentry/demo-rq

Comment: So the only other thing that might be causing an issue that I can think of is that we're starting the worker threads through supervisor.  Otherwise I really have no idea why this isn't working correctly.

Comment: So I stopped supervisor and ran the worker manually, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Can you share code (is this open source or closed?) Also did you try running my demo code? This might also be better resolved over support@getsentry.com and the final solution cross-posted here.

Comment: Unfortunately this is closed source.  Your example gives me an error about not being able to connect to redis. `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.`  Even when attempting to put in the proper host for my local dockerized redis server, I get the same error.  I haven't had much time to looked into this yet, however.

Comment: Oh, but my Sentry does show that error, so that does seem to be working!

Comment: I'll look into this more tomorrow to figure out what exactly is going on.  So far it doesn't appear to be anything to do with `StrictRedis` vs `Redis`.